# Can I disable model binding and use the raw request body in an action in dotnet core?

Tags: .net-core

I want to setup an endpoint for testing webhooks from third parties.  Their documentation is uniformly poor and there is no way ahead of time to tell exactly what I will be getting.  What I've done is setup an ApiController that will just take a request and add a row to a table with what they are sending.  This lets me at least verify they are calling the webhook, and to see the data so I can program to it.

```
// ANY api/webook/*
[Route("{*path}")]
public ActionResult Any(string path)
{
    string method = Request.Method;
    string name = "path";
    string apiUrl = Request.Path;
    string apiQuery = Request.QueryString.ToString();
    string apiHeaders = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Headers);
    string apiBody = null;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        apiBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    Add(method, name, apiUrl, apiQuery, apiHeaders, apiBody);
    return new JsonResult(new { }, JsonSettings.Default);
}
```

This works great, except for this new webhook I am usign that posts as form data so some middleware is reading the body and it ends up null in my code.  Is there any way to disable the model processing so I can get at the request body?

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use model binding to your advantage and skip all that stream reading, using the `FromBody` attribute. Try this:

```
[Route("{*path}")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Any(string path, [FromBody] string apiBody)
```